# Should I not install MYSQL community server in my device that has my own application running and sell that device without exposing my source code?

Tags: mysql

I have a device which I am plannig to sell along with my application.
My application is a mysql client.
Also, I have installed mysql server in my device.
My application which is a mysql client interacts with this mysql server I have installed in my device.

Mysql - community version
Version - 8.0.27

As per the licensing can I have this without exposing my application's source code to the person I sell? Each one interprets this GPL v2 in their own way. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but have to prepare your code, and MySQL on this device, applying the correct user and password on your database.

### But I have some advice for you.

##### Server files

Your server will run your database on this device, and all database files will be stored in it. For example :

```
*.ibz   Compressed form of InnoDB data files from the MySQL data directory.
*.frm   Hold metadata about all MySQL tables.
*.MYD   MyISAM table data.
*.MYI   MyISAM index data.
```

This file could be copied or accessed easily. Even if your MySQL installed on this machine has a user and password configured, you can have your data exposed.

##### Application files

Your code will be opened, if you use a not compiled project, so all your work and the database password, could be stolen. If this is the case, one option could be protect your code using tools like **[Zend Guard](https://www.zend.com/products/zend-guard)** or some similar tool.

Maybe this is not a problem to your project but this is a question that only you can answer.

Comment: My question is not about the privacy of my code. It is rather about the terms of GPL v2 licensing.

Answer (score 0):

Little vague.
Could have split this into two questions.
Licensing and
Source Code Exposure.

If your mysql client is in php / perl / etc, it is exposed when you sell the device. Instead if you load a compiled product, your source is hidden.

If you could more details by editing your question, I shall give specific answer.

Comment: It is a node js mysql client. I am not worried about my source code being exposed. Should I expose it myself as per the GPL licensing?

Comment: Yes - I mentioned that your question is vague. As per your question's last line - without exposing my application's source code to the person I sell?.

Comment: It is anyway your developed code. If you are giving a free product, you are usually expected to give access to your code by default.